# Change UILabel attributed String

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I use this code to add attributed strings to a label:

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
// add some attributes
myLabel.attributedText = attrString
```

Now is it possible to change only the text of the attributed string myLabel and keeping the attributes?

Comment: Yeah it is possible. But you have to do by attributed string.

Comment: As far I know. Nope. Each and every time label set attributed text also with the attributed dictionary. If you want to make that previous attribute as function or globe variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through it's `mutableString` property

Example:

```
let astrMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World")

//set some attributes
astrMessage.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor,
                         value: UIColor.blue,
                         range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
astrMessage.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor,
                         value: UIColor.red,
                         range: NSRange(location: 6, length: 5))

//update
astrMessage.mutableString.setString("World Welcome")
```

NOTE: Only the first attribute will be applied to the updated text.

Answer (score 0):

get your label attribute

```
let linkAttributes = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText)
```

you can give add attribute.

```
linkAttributes.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "username://marcelofabri_", range: linkRange)
let linkAttributes: [String : Any] = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green,
    NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray,
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
```

Add Attributed text to your label

```
myLabel.attributedText = linkAttributes
```

Comment: And how does this answer OP's question? You didn't show how to change the attributed string's string property without changing the attributes...

Comment: you can get label attribute and change any one

Comment: `let newAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText) `   use newAttributedString  to edit any attribute

Comment: Maybe include the relevant code in your __answer__ instead of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mutable string of your attributed string and reassign the NSMutableAttributedString to your label.

```
attrString.mutableString.setString("newText")
myLabel.attributedText = attrString
```

**P.S**
If you do not have the access to your attributed string variable, get it from the label.

```
let myAttrString = myLabel.attributedText as? NSMutableAttributedString
if let attrString = myAttrString {
    attrString.mutableString.setString("newText")
    myLabel.attributedText = attrString
}
```